# Embers View - loose content

Tags: ember.js

I have a rails app with ember that render one template where i want to render the app´s notes list.

The main template is :

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px">
   ......
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header">list notes</li>
 #ERROR -> {{  view App.NotesListView contentBinding='App.NotesIndexController' }}
        </ul>
      </div>
      {{#linkTo "notes.new"}} <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>{{/linkTo}}
    </div>
  ......
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the notes_index_controller:

```
App.NotesIndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend

  init: ->
    console.log "entra en notes index controller"

  selectedResource: null

  isEmpty:( ->
    @get('length') == 0
  ).property('length')
```

and the index_route :

```
App.NotesIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend

  model: ->
    App.Note.find()


  setupController:(controller, model ) ->
    controller.set('content', model )
    controller.set('users', App.User.find() )
```

When i try to render this view ( App.NotesListView ) :

```
App.NotesListView = Ember.View.extend

  templateName: "notes/list"
```

list.hbs

```
{{#each content}}  #I supose that have to be the NotesIndex´s content but not it is
  <li>test</li>
  <li>{{  view App.NoteListItemView contentBinding='this' }}</li>
{{/each}}
```

I cann´t bind the NotesIndexController ( where i get the list of notes ) with the content of this view.

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: is your main template `index` or `application`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main template is `index` you should be able to access your `App.NotesIndexController` content by requiring the `nodesIndex` controller with the needs API in your `IndexController`:

#### JS

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  content: []
  needs: ['notesIndex']
  notesBinding: 'controllers.notesIndex.content'
```

#### Handlebars

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  ...
  {{view App.NotesListView contentBinding='notes'}}
  ...
</script>
```

If your main template is `application` you should be able to do the same but requiring your `notesIndex` controller on the `ApplicationController` instead:

#### JS

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  content: []
  needs: ['notesIndex']
  notesBinding: 'controllers.notesIndex.content'
```

#### Handlebars

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
  ...
  {{view App.NotesListView contentBinding='notes'}}
  ...
</script>
```

#### Edit in response to your last comment:

try rewrite the `setupController` hook in you `NotesIndexRoute` to this:

```
  ...
  setupController:(controller, model) ->
    @_super(controller, model)
    controller.set('users', App.User.find())
  ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get this error: "Assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('notes', (null)) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.IndexController:ember271>: its 'content' is undefined. "

Comment: @user1727442, changed `ObjectController` to `ArrayController` try again

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because it doesnot render the list of notes. I uploaded the example to github : https://github.com/villanopack/ember-example-notes/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/templates/index.hbs

Comment: @user1727442, another try, this time a correction in your `NotesIndexRoute` `setupController` hook

Comment: I get the same result, the user list is not render. I have pulled a second commit :(

Comment: @user1727442, looking at your last commit, the line `    controller.set('users', App.User.find())` is removed, was it intentionaly?

Comment: To avoid any error, because i am focused in render the note model and i dont find what is wrong and why is not the list rendered